# Why is my service provider limiting my htacess use?

Tags: apache, server, silex

and in the process making my life more difficult?

Bluehost will not let me use

```
# no access to this it seems
#DocumentRoot /public_html

# access to this however
#DirectoryIndex
```

and their docs say I need to use

```
# change the document root using rewrite rules per bluehost document
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?foo.com$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?foo.com$
#RewriteRule ^(/)?$ web/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that problem before, but it looks like they have updated access so that you can use `DirecotryIndex`.

See the Bluehost documentation [here.](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/184-provider-limiting-my-htacess-use)

For `DocumentRoot` they have a work around [here](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347).

Your web framework lists yet another solution [here](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```